# Was the timing of Grunkle Stan's cane swing intentional?

Tags: soundtrack, animation, gravity-falls

During the opening theme to Gravity Falls, at approximately six seconds in, Grunkle Stan can be seen swinging his cane in the direction of the mystery shack:

His smokescreen appearance and cane swing (which occurs in two steps) seem to be intentionally synchronized with the music, which I presume isn't all that uncommon in movies and TV, but is there any official information on this?

Comment: Syncing thing up with the music is pretty much ubiquitous in animation. I can't think of any other medium that does it so commonly. I'd be *flabbergasted* if this wasn't intentional.

Comment: Every movement of a character, object, or the camera is in time with the beat of the theme song.  Cuts happen at the beginning of every measure, or sometimes after two measures - that is, once per 4 or 8 beats (more or less - some cuts actually happen on a pickup note).